# How to write Huge dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have pandas dataframe size of 21909, 20037 (row,column) and I want to convert it to csv by following code.

```
dpF.to_csv("outputFile.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

after this line of code my computer is getting hang and I am not getting any output.
Is there any way to write such a huge dataframe in a optimal way.

> System configuration
>
> - **OS**: ubuntu 16.04 LTS
> - **OS type**: 64 bit
> - **Memory**: 7.7 GiB
> - **Processor**: Intel® Core™ i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4

Comment: try to use `chunksize=1000` parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`chunksize` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv("outputFile.csv", encoding='utf-8', chunksize=2000)
```

> **chunksize** : int or None
>
> rows to write at a time